# How to use <br> tag as variable

Tags: javascript

Anyone knows how to make br tag as variable?
I want to output a txt file that has textbox value.
I want to set a specific counts of break lines. Like 100 times.

Example. 
Hello
Earth

Output
Hello
(line break 100times)
Earth

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) to repeat a string N times :

```js
const a_lot_of_new_lines = "<br>".repeat(100);
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "Hello" + a_lot_of_new_lines + "Earth";
```

```html
<div id="foo">
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare

```
const new_line = "<br>";
```

And then use ES6 [String.prototype.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```
const content = "Hello" + new_line.repeat(100) + "Earth";
document.querySelector(".your-class").innerHTML = content;
```

Another way is to create custom function with recursion for this. For example:

```
function repeatString(string, times) {
  if (times < 0) {
    return "";
  } else if (times === 1) {
    return string;
  } else {
    return string + repeatString(string, times - 1);
  }
```

And `repeatString(new_line, 3)` will return result wanted.